# Basic Python function

Tags: python

I am trying to complete two different questions but cannot get them to work. Please help me understand where I went wrong.

1) For each number between 1 and 100, odds should be normal and even numbers should print out the word "Billy". Must start at 1 not 0 and include the number 100. Here's my answer (I know I'm way off)

```
for i in range(1,101):

    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(Billy)

    else:    
        print(i)
```

2) Ask the user: "What is your name?". Response should look like "Hello Billy" for all names except Joe and Susie. For Joe it should say "Hi Joe :)" and for susie it should say "Ahoy Susie :D". Here is where I'm at:

```
name = input("What is your name?")

if name == "Joe":
    print("Hi Joe :)")

if name == "Susie":
      print("Ahoy Susie :D)

else: print("Hello", name)
```

Comment: Please format your code as code.

Comment: for Q1 watch out for indentation inside the `for` loop and the `else` clause. Also `Billy` is not in the namespace. Otherwise good job.

Comment: Is this your *actual* indentation?  As in, do you get errors if you run your code from non-indented lines?

Comment: No its the editor. I can edit it. How do I make it look like my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
for i in range(1,101):

    if i % 2 == 0:
       print('Billy') #you missed quote marks here

    else:
       print(i)
```

(bad indentation, and missing quote marks)

and

```
name = input("What is your name?")

if name == "Joe":
    print("Hi Joe :)")

elif name == "Susie":
    print("Ahoy Susie :D") #and you missed quote marks here

else: 
   print("Hello" + name)
```

...same issues.

Comment: You don't know if this is a copy-and-paste error from their editor as far as indentation is concerned.  It's also possible to place an `if` statement on the same line as the colon.

Comment: I didn't claim the inline if was a cause of error, i just made it look nicer. Either way, it is a neater and correct answer...?

Comment: I'm not very fluent in python, but your comments are wrong, your last print looks off as well (concat operator in python is `+`) and try your code with "Joe" as input, you'll notice a problem.

Comment: Alright, you changed the comments when I posted :-) Still, your last print should be `print("Hello "+ name")` and the second `if` of the second exercise should be a `elif`.

Comment: It prints twice for Joe like this: What is your name?Hi Joe :) 
Hello Joe

Comment: yes that is because i forgot to make it elif. try since my update. Sorry - i should have looked further than the stand out syntax errors.

Comment: It worked. I had to change back to `("Hello", name)`. The `+` didnt put a space

Comment: Okay - well the + and , really does not matter much. A comma is used for outputting different data types inline - which doesn't actually apply here. So really you should just do `print("Hello "+name)` (with a space after the 'o') where the + concatenates the string.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I appreciate you being tolerant of someone learning a new skill